# Mysterious navigation controller bar gone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

It has happened more than once, but today, something even more mysterious happened to me. After restarting my macbook and reopening Xcode, 3 of my views lost their navigation bars on the interface builder.

Like so:
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg4wj.png

However, running it on the simulator still shows the navigation toolbar on the top of the screen.

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/60iQG.png

Any idea on what's happening here? I restarted my computer once again, to see if that changes anything, but to no avail.

This problem also happens sometimes, when I place a brand new view controller and embed a navigation controller into it. The toolbar simply doesn't show on the view in the interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar in your app is generated by the navigation controller at run-time.

Interface builder has to "simulate" the run time look and content of a navigation bar, and it has to work out which controllers to apply it to.

You can also manually request a simulated navigation bar (and tab bar etc) in the  settings for each view controller.